# How many sphere on the boundary of a big sphere?

Tags: geometry, general-topology

I don't know exactly how to ask this in a comprehensible way.

I am trying to find a solution to my problem which is to find how many sphere of radius r are lying on the boundary (which means that in some way  this little sphere intersect the boundary of the big sphere) of a sphere of radius R (with r smaller than R).

For example, one simple law could be dividing the surface area of the sphere with radius R with the area of a circle of radius r.

Comment: Do you mean tangent to the big sphere ? Inside or outside ?

Comment: Can you tell a bit more? Are the centers of the small spheres all on the surface of the big sphere. Presumably the small spheres are not allowed to intersect each other or...? Can we choose the locations of the centers of the small spheres ourselves (some inside, some outside)?

Answer (score 1):

This is a packing problem.  Problems like this are hard.  If you go to the [Wikipedia page on packing circles into circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle) or search the web for circle packing into circles you will find that many of the arrangements are not regular.  Your case will be similar.  A reasonable estimate for $r$ rather smaller than $R$ comes from considering the solid angle subtended by each small sphere.  As its center is $r+R$ from the center of the large sphere it subtends a solid angle of about $\frac {\pi r^2}{(R+r)^2}$.  We divide this into the total solid angle of $4 \pi$ and multiply by $\frac {3 \sqrt 3}{2 \pi}$ which is the fraction of the area covered by a circle in hexagonal packing.  The last is an attempt to account for the wasted space between the small spheres.  This gives $\frac {3 \sqrt 3}{2 \pi}\cdot \frac {4 \pi (R+r)^2}{\pi r^2}=\frac {6 \sqrt 3(R+r)^2}{ \pi r^2}$

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. Of course I can tell you more. What I am doing is modelling the mechanical behavior of grain and subgrain in dynamic recrystallization. If you look deep into metals, you will see that they are made by grains and inside those grains there are subgrains, that are smaller. In certain case the subgrains on the boundary can grows and become bigger.

I am modelling the grains and subgrains as spheres.
Now, if you look the shapes of grains they are completely different from a sphere:

[elementary volume of a undefined metal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9olrW.png)

and think that inside each grain there is a not well defined number of subgrains (the dimension of those subgrains is modeled using a probability density function, so when I talk of the radius r of the subgrain I am referring to the mean value of the distribution).

There is also a main problem in modelling grain and subgrain as sphere, is that there should not be empty spaces inside the big sphere (inside the grain) and I actually don't know if this can still be possible in some way.

In reality the subgrains are inside of the grain (which means that in the model the little sphere have to be tangent inside the big sphere). However I can try several option and see which one works better (so sphere tangent outside, center of the small sphere on the surface of the big one and so on....).